# flutter snackbar (with dismiss button)is not disappearing

Tags: flutter, hide, dismiss, snackbar

I have created a snackbar with a button inside snacbar named 'undo' and also i have set snackbar duration property to 2 seconds but the snackbar is not hiding after to 2 seconds if i don't use the 'undo' button in snacbar action the duration property is working but with this button it is not working

I tried to hide snackbar automatically after 2 second with a button inside it called 'undo' or 'dismiss' but it is not hiding
and here is the sample code :
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
content: const Text(
'the item was successfully deleted!'),
action: SnackBarAction(
label: 'undo',
onPressed: () async {
await SqlHelper.createItemWithID(
deletedItem![0]['id'],
deletedItem![0]['title'],
deletedItem![0]['description'],
deletedItem![0]['createdAt']);
counterFordeleteditem -= 1;
await RecyclebinHHHHHelper.deleteItemm(
deletedItem![0]['id']);

```
                              refresh();
                            },
                          ),
                        ));
                      
                        Future.delayed(
                            Duration(seconds:2), () {
                         
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                .hideCurrentSnackBar();
                        });
```

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet

Comment: Edit the question including the source code of `Snackbar`.

Comment: i  wrote my code in answers Section(i do not know how to edit the question)

Answer (score -1):

```
snackbar.setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Handle undo action here
    }
});
snackbar.show();

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (snackbar.isShown()) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: this is flutter question, what the hell you post here.